# Error with Missing Assembly

Tags: arcgis-server

I have a webADF based website that I am trying to deploy. It's giving me this error. I have made sure that I have installed all the components that come from ArcGIS Server Installation media (GISServices, WebADF Runtime, WebApplications)

My server environment is: Windows Server 2008 R2, ArcGIS Server 10, IIS7

I am not sure what else it needs to find the DLL.

Apprecaite any feedback. 
Thanks
Jay

[image]